# How to debug page rendering in Mobile Chrome (CSS transition effects)?

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transitions, gpu

The reason I'm asking is because I'm getting low FPS on Android Chrome during a slide transition that uses `transform:translateX`.

Notice the FPS drops in my screenshot. Those happen during the transition. Is there any way to get a list of browser events or some kind of information that tells me what did the browser during that time?

[image: Chrome - Android 4.2.2 - Nexus 4]

Answer (score -1):

You can connect the device to your PC (with Chrome Canary installed) and the use Android Chrome Remote Debugging: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/remote-debugging